# Vue UI not updating with state changes, until I hover over it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm making a button to track changes in save state.

I basically have some classes being applied when I get either a success/failure response from the save.  This works fine.

The part that doesn't work is the selective text inside my button.

```
   export default {
      name: "saveButton",
      components: {spinner},
      data: function() {
        return {
          hover: false
        }
      },
      props: ['handleSubmit', 'isSaving', 'saveStatus'],
      methods: {
        submit() {
          this.$emit("handleSubmit")
        },
        mouseOver(value) {
          this.hover = value;
        }
      },
      computed: {
        buttonClass() {
          if (this.saveStatus == 'success') {
            return 'save-success'
          }
          else if (this.saveStatus == 'failure') {
            return 'save-failed'
          }
          else {
            return ''
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
    <template>
      <div class="settings--button-wrapper">
        <button class="btn btn--small"
                :class="buttonClass"
                type="button"
                @click="submit()"
                v-if="!isSaving"
                v-on:mouseover="mouseOver(true)"
                v-on:mouseleave="mouseOver(false)"
        >
          <span v-if="this.saveStatus == '' || this.hover">Save</span>
          <span v-if="this.saveStatus == 'failure' && !this.hover">Save failed</span>
          <span v-if="this.saveStatus == 'success' && !this.hover">Saved!</span>
        </button>
        <spinner v-if="isSaving" class="settings--spinner">
          <span>Saving...</span>
        </spinner>
      </div>
    </template>
```

When I get a failed response, my computed method updates my class and the button turns red.  `this.saveStatus` is updated also, however my button text still says just "Save", not "Save failed".

So it's this part specifically that isn't updating initially:-

```
              <span v-if="this.saveStatus == '' || this.hover">Save</span>
              <span v-if="this.saveStatus == 'failure' && !this.hover">Save failed</span>
              <span v-if="this.saveStatus == 'success' && !this.hover">Saved!</span>
```

The odd thing is, when I hover over the button, it THEN picks up the changes, and sticks on "Save failed" when I hover away from it.

**Update**: I've realised the cause is that when I move my mouse away quickly after clicking save - the `v-on:mouseleave` event isn't actually catching my mouse moving away in time, so my `hover` variable is set to true - which keeps my 'Save' text showing.

Any idea why this is happening or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer turned out to be because when I was clicking Save, the `isSaving` variable kicked in and made the button element disappear - so no `mouseleave` event was being registered - which is why it was still thinking it was in a hover state.